# Reading an image into pygame with incorrect file extension

Tags: python, image, pygame

I want to load a JPS file into pygame. A JPS file is simply a jpeg file with the image consisting of two side by side stereo pictures. While Pigame will load it in if I change the extension to jpg and use pygame.image.load(file_name), what I want to do is to load the file into memory and then tell Pigame to load the file in from a buffer and that the buffer contains a jpeg file.

I would like to do it this way because later I want to extend things so that I can load in an MPO file which is a file that contains two jpeg files and I suspect that the same techniques will be involved.

I have tried the pygame.image.frombuffer and pygame.image.fromstring but get the error message that the "String length does not equal format and resolution size". I think this is because I am not telling it that the buffer contains a jpeg.

Any one have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Since `pygame.image.load()` will accept either a filename or a Python file-like object, seems like you could first read the JPS file into a `StringIO` instance, and then pass that to it.

Comment: How do you mean? imagebuf = StringIO(file_name)
image1 = pygame.image.load(imagebuf)
gives
Unsupported image format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines (untested):

```
with open('image.jps', 'rb') as imgfile:
    imgbuf = StringIO(imgfile.read())

image1 = pygame.image.load(imgbuf)
```

Since you say it works, you could probably shorten things as shown below since there's no reason to give the image buffer a name and keep it around:

```
with open('image.jps', 'rb') as imgfile:
    image1 = pygame.image.load(StringIO(imgfile.read()))
```

Comment: Good to hear — you're welcome. BTW, tohandle the MPO file you will probably have to extract each jpeg into a separate `StringIO` instance since pygame would have no idea how to do that itself.

Comment: Thanks - yes I have broken the back of it today and I am reading and displaying the two images in an mpo file. However I had to read the file twice to get the two instances. Without adding to "question creep" is there a way of only reading it once? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: In my answer, `imgfile.read()` reads the whole file into memory and returns the data read as a string, which is then used to create a single `StringIO` instance. You could create multiple instances from it by using slice notation on the returned string and then creating a separate `StringIO` instance out of each of the slices — assuming you know the starting and ending byte offset of each of the embedded images. i.e. `image1 = pygame.image.load(StringIO(imgbuf[start1:end1+1]))`, `image2 = pygame.image.load(StringIO(imgbuf[start2:end2+1]))`, etc.